# I got stuck when trying to connect prisma with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, prisma

`schema.prisma`:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  // previewFeatures = ["views"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

Error:

> Error: MongoDB error
> Kind: An error occurred during DNS resolution: proto error: io error: 通訊端操作嘗試連線到一個無法連線的網路。 (os error 10051), labels: {}
>
> 0: schema_core::commands::schema_push::Calculate `from`
> at schema-engine\core\src\commands\schema_push.rs:29
>
> 1: schema_core::state::SchemaPush
> at schema-engine\core\src\state.rs:436

I am trying to connect prisma schema with MongoDB engine. However, I do not know why there could be an error of the proto. Could anyone help me figure out what the connection problem is?